# Equations of the secant variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ be an irreducible nondegenerate (i.e. not contained in a hyperplane) projective complex algebraic variety, and let $\mathrm{Sec}(X)$ be the secant variety of $X$ (i.e. the union of all secant lines of $X$).
Further suppose that the homogeneous ideal of $X$ is generated by forms $F_1,\ldots,F_m$ of degree two.

How do I write the equations of $\mathrm{Sec}(X)$ as a function of $F_0,\ldots,F_m$ ?

Let us focus attention on the simplest case, i.e. when $\mathrm{Sec}(X)$ is a cubic hypersurface. Then we have 
$\mathrm{Sec}(X)=V(G(x_0,\ldots,x_N))$, where $G(x_0,\ldots,x_N)=\sum_{i=1}^m L_i(x_0,\ldots,x_N) F_i(x_0,\ldots,x_N)$. 
The linear forms $L_0,\ldots,L_N$ depend only by $F_0,\ldots,F_N$, but how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The computation of explicit equations of secant varieties is hard in general.
However, things are simpler when one works with *determinantal varieties*, i.e. varieties whose equations are given by some minors of a matrix of homogeneous forms.

In fact, there is the following result, that one can find in [Harris, Algebraic Geometry, p. 145]:

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be the projective space of $m \times n$ matrices and let $M_k \subset M$ be the subvariety of matrices of rank at most $k$. Assume that $2k < \min\{m, n\}$. Then the secant variety $S(M_k)$ is equal to the subariety $M_{2k} \subset M$ of matrices of rank at most $2k$.

As an example, let us consider the Veronese surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$, whose equations are the $2 \times 2$ minors of the matrix
$$ M:=\pmatrix{z_0 & z_3 & z_4 \cr z_3 & z_1 & z_5 \cr z_4 & z_5 & z_2}.$$
In this case $m=n=3$ and $k=1$, that is $X=M_1$.  Then the secant variety $S(X)$ coincides with the determinantal variety $M_2$, i.e. with the cubic hypersurface defined by $$\det M=0.$$
This is essentially due to the fact that the linear combination of two rank $1$ matrices can have rank at most $2$.

Developing the determinant along any line or column, you can find an expression of the equation of $S(X)$ as a linear combination of generators of the homogeneous ideal $I(X)$.

Moreover, in the same way one can find equations for the secant varieties of rational normal curves, see [Harris, Algebraic geometry, p. 103].

For a deeper treatment of this problem, see the paper by Ottaviani and Landsberg *Equations for secant varieties of Veronese and other varieties*, [arXiv:1111.4567](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4567).

Answer (score 8):

If  $I(X)$, the ideal of $X$ is empty  in degrees less than $d$, then there can be no equations
of the secant variety until degree $d+1$, and the ideal in degree $d+1$ consists
of all polynomials $P$ such that all partials of $P$ are in $I_d(X)$. There is a similar
description for the ideal of the secant variety in higher degrees which I call "multi-prolongation",
but one does not know when one has generators for the ideal by this method, and it
becomes very difficult to compute. In your case,
since you have a hypersurface the termination problem does not arise - your cubic is the unique cubic all of whose partial derivatives are in the ideal of $X$.